# What is the meaning of '!' in ldm arm assembler instruction?

Tags: assembly, arm, gas

I am quite new to ARM assembly, I already saw that the bang (`!`) is used to really update a register after a computation in the addressing mode syntax, but I can't figure out what is the difference of semantics between (this output is from `objdump` so it uses `gas` syntax):

```
ldm r4!, {r0, r1, r2, r3}
```

And:

```
ldm r4, {r0, r1, r2, r3}
```

Any idea ?

Comment: By the way, you can use Intel syntax with objdump, just specify `objdump -M intel`

Comment: @JamalS: there's no Intel syntax for ARM

Comment: @JamalS: You should have noticed that register list is not something common in x86 operands. :-)

Comment: @perror: Yes, I forgot x86 starts at r8 instead of r0 :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `!` denotes *writeback of the base register*. **Base register** is the register used to address the memory to be read or written - in your case it's `R4`. **Writeback** means that the base register will be updated with the delta equal to the size of transferred data.

So, the instruction

```
ldm r4!, {r0, r1, r2, r3}
```

can be represented by the following pseudocode:

```
r0 = *(int)(r4) 
r1 = *(int)(r4+4) 
r2 = *(int)(r4+8) 
r3 = *(int)(r4+12) 
r4 = r4 + 16 // writeback (16 bytes transferred)
```

In the variant without `!` the writeback doesn't happen so `R4` retains the original value.

In the `LDR` and `STR` instructions you may also encounter *pre-indexed* and *post-indexed* notation:

```
LDR R0, [R4, #4]  ; simple offset: R0 = *(int*)(R4+4); R4 unchanged
LDR R0, [R4, #4]! ; pre-indexed:   R0 = *(int*)(R4+4); R4 = R4+4
LDR R0, [R4], #4  ; post-indexed:  R0 = *(int*)(R4+0); R4 = R4+4
```

For more information see the [ARM Assembler Guide](http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/armasm/).